# Count number of consecutive entries with Arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to count the number of consecutive times the same value appears until the given row, until another value appears then start counting from zero again. And I want to use an `arrayformula` so I don’t have to copy it down all rows.

```
Input   Count
Foo        1
Foo        2
Foo        3
Bar        
Bar        
Foo        1
Foo        2
```

A way that works is something like this if you copy it all the way down:

`=IF( A2="Foo", 1, B1+1 )`

The problem is a formula like this doesn’t work for `arrayformula`, because you can’t reference the preceding row, because this gives you an error for circular dependencies.

I think some combination of `filter`, `query` and `countif` might work but can‘t figure out how.

EDIT: I tried to use `mmult` as suggested but that doesn’t seem to be able to solve the problem, because I can only count row by row. I can count all the rows with a certain value like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(N(
    ROW(A2:A)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW( A2:A))),
    N(A2:A="Foo"))
)
```

but I can’t reset the counter each time a different input appears.

Comment: We know that the first row result always will be one, so, add 1 on the first row, and the formula on the second row and below.

Comment: This works like stated in the post if you copy the formula, but it won’t work with an arrayformula unfortunatly, because those don’t allow to reference a row that is affected by the array formula itself.

Comment: I think that some users will require the information in my comment. Regarding the question, try MMULT. For a similar question, with an answer using MMULT, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88840/using-arrayformula-to-compute-running-decremented-total-subtracting-the-previou/91074#91074

Comment: Another answer using MMULT: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/99772/88163

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to MMULT. Definitely seems like a good approach to running totals, but I am completely lost, as to how I could use that, to achieve that only the rows with the same value in A are counted. Basically what I need is a way take the current value in A, and then count up, until I reach a row, where A has a different value.

Comment: I think that somewhere I already posted an answer a to a similar question, not sure in English or Spanish, I will search for it later.

Comment: I actually got doubts `MMULT`can solve that problem. I can easily count all rows that have a certain value, like this:

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(N(ROW(A2:A)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(
A2:A)));N(A2:A="A")))`

But I can’t check how many have been consecutive since the last time the input was something else then it is in the current row.

I can neither seem to be able to keep different “counting lists” for different inputs. But to make things easier it would be enough to just count the consecutive appearances of a certain value.

Comment: Add that to the question, please.

Comment: I did, also simplified the problem to the core of „restarting“ the counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Summary

Below there are two alternatives, one that uses `MMULT` which doesn't require an auxiliary formula and one that uses `SUMIF` but it requieres an auxiliary formula.

NOTE: Open ended references could make that recalculation time be very large. One alternative to reduce recalculation time is to remove empty rows below the data, another is to use `FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A))` instead of using just `A2:A`.

### Formula with MMULT

This doesn't require an auxiliary column

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(
    A2:A8="Foo",
    MMULT(N(ROW(A2:A8)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A8))),N(A2:A8="Foo"))
    -
    HLOOKUP(
      0,
      MMULT(N(ROW(A2:A8)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A8))),N(A2:A8="Foo")),
      MATCH(
        VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A8),IF(N(A2:A8<>A1:A7),ROW(A2:A8),),1,TRUE),
        VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A8),IF(N(A2:A8<>A1:A7),ROW(A2:A8),),1,TRUE),
        0
      ),
      FALSE
    ),
  )
)
```

### Formula with SUMIF

This require an auxiliary formula, becaus SUMIF require a reference, as the third argument

#### Auxiliary formula

Formula in B2: `=ArrayFormula(N(A2:A8="Foo"))`

#### Main formula

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(
    A2:A8="Foo",
    SUMIF(ROW(A2:A8),"<="&ROW(A2:A8),B2:B8)
    -
    HLOOKUP(
      0,
      SUMIF(ROW(A2:A8),"<"&ROW(A2:A8),B2:B8),
      MATCH(
        VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A8),IF(N(A2:A8<>A1:A7),ROW(A2:A8),),1,TRUE),
        VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A8),IF(N(A2:A8<>A1:A7),ROW(A2:A8),),1,TRUE),
        FALSE),
      FALSE
    ),
  )
)
```

## Reference

[Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69855/88163) by AdamL to [ArrayFormula to compute Running Average for groups of rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69778/arrayformula-to-compute-running-average-for-groups-of-rows)

Comment: I haven’t fully wrapped my head around what is going on in these forumals, but it definitely works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on my matrix.  A bit different.  Column E is calculating the consecutive days of weight loss.  The formula is `=IF(C4="","",IF(C4>0,IF(E3="",1,E3+1),""))`.

```
                     4 lbs lost       1 lbs average daily loss  Days of Consecutive Weight Loss
Weight Loss Tracker  Morning Weight   Daily weight loss     
9/21/2021            195.2          
9/22/2021            192.2            3.00  lbs                 1
9/23/2021            191.2            1.00  lbs                 2
9/24/2021            191               .20  lbs                 3
9/25/2021            195             -4.00  lbs     
9/26/2021            192              3.00  lbs                 1
9/27/2021            191              1.00  lbs                 2
9/28/2021               
9/29/2021               
9/30/2021
```